# aws - lambda - python - firing up to 4x on s3 object created triggers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have some simple lambda functions that are always getting fired up to 4x on almost every S3 Object Created (All) trigger and I can't seem to figure out why.

The files are relatively small right now, only a few KB, coming from Kinesis Firehose.

In the screenshot below, everything with a "File:" in the beginning of the message is a duplicate call on the same file written. The "Uploading:" part is where the function uploads the file to a different folder that has a lambda function watching (that one too executes multiple times!). That only happened once in the screenshot, but I've seen it happen multiple times.

[image]
I did add some code so when the function is executed it first checks an s3 folder for a blank file to see if it's already been processed or not, and if not then proceed. This catches some of the dupe executions, problem I'm seeing is sometimes the lambda function is executing twice within near the same millisecond so this check is obviously no good.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')
    print "File: "+bucket+"/"+key

    exists = False    
    tmp_f = key.replace('firehose/','')
    tmp_f = tmp_f.split('/')
    tmp_f_date = tmp_f[0]+"-"+tmp_f[1]+"-"+tmp_f[2]
    tmp_f_name = "folder/"+tmp_f_date+"/"+tmp_f[0]+"-"+tmp_f[1]+"-"+tmp_f[2]+"-"+tmp_f[3]+"____"+(tmp_f[4].replace('.gz','.txt'))
    try:
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, tmp_f_name, '/tmp/tmpf')
        if os.path.isfile('/tmp/tmpf'):
            exists = True
            print "--> File exists..."
    except:
        print "--> New file..."
        pass

    if exists == True: return False
    open('/tmp/tmpf', 'a').close()
    s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/tmpf', bucket, tmp_f_name)
    return process_file() # returns True
```

Doing some researching I'm not finding a solid solution. Some say this is the nature of lambda, "at least once" execution and to keep track of the request ID but we're seeing executions fire within a millisecond or two of each other so we'd have to have a redis instance just to keep track? The S3 file method above is apparently too slow.

This doesn't seem optimal so I'm HOPING I'm missing maybe a line of code or callback? Someone please help :)

Comment: we use redshift for our final destination after another lambda does more post processing. Perhaps I should just use a transaction sql check instead of the s3 file above? I still don't like how amazon bills us up to 4x for executions if this is just the way it is...

Comment: This is definitely not just the way it is. It should be 1:1.  Log the value of `event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['sequencer']`.  This is an internal S3 transaction log sequence number.  If this hexadecimal number is incrementing, then something is actually writing the same object (an object with the same key) to S3 multiple times, so multiple invocations is correct and the problem is upstream.  (The increment isn't monotonic -- there are gaps -- but for one object key, a different number is always a different upload, and a larger number is always a later upload). What do you see?

Comment: Oddly enough, I haven't had one duplicate execution since I posted this about 4 hours ago. I added a line of code to log the sequencer id, so if this issue comes back I'll reply here. The S3 file is coming from Kinesis Firehose so it could be there was an issue with firehose writing the same file multiple times or something causing my lambda functions to go haywire, who knows at this point. Just glad my inbox isn't getting cloudwatch errors left right and center anymore :)

Comment: And issue is back... Sequencer number on duplicate executions is identical

Comment: I did **not** expect that.  Oh... what about `event['Records'][0]['eventName']`?  Is that also identical?  Sorry I didn't consider that possibility before but fingers crossed that it's not also the same.  While you are at it, log the value of `context.aws_request_id`.

Comment: sequence id, request id, event name are all identical. We tried using redis to keep track of processing requests however doesn't change the fact we were seeing too many fires on same files which means wasted costs. Ultimately decided to use a cheap EC2 instance for now to take place of lambda functions. No idea where the hiccup would be, might be our vpc config was causing lambda functions to randomly fail/rety, we don't know at this point. So bummed, when it worked we had a perfect kinesis firehose --> lambda post processing --> redshift with zero maintenance!!!

Comment: Given one set of identical events, what's the timing of them relative to each other?  Is there any evidence of errors or failures?  You should probably post this to the official support forum and see if an insider picks it up and asks you to PM them some event IDs for investigation.  Widespread brokenness of the service seems highly unlikely but not entirely impossible.

Comment: I did post a topic over at the support forums though the few times I did I don't think I've ever got a response back. Usually they are fired within a few seconds of each other, sometimes within the same second. Since moving the functions that process the firehose feed out of vpc, we haven't seen a duplicate invoke, so I'm thinking maybe it was our vpc setup. It's really the only thing that might make any sense. Thanks for your time on this :)